# Policy-based template design: How to access certain policies of the class?

Tags: c++, oop, templates, template-meta-programming, policy

I have a class that uses several policies that are templated. It is called `Dish` in the following example. I store many of these `Dish`es in a `vector` (using a pointer to simple base class), but then I'd like to extract and use them. But I don't know their exact types.

Here is the code; it's a bit long, but really simple:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct DishBase {
  int id;
  DishBase(int i) : id(i) {}
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const DishBase& d) {
  out << d.id;
  return out;
}

// Policy-based class:
template<class Appetizer, class Main, class Dessert>
class Dish : public DishBase {
  Appetizer appetizer_;
  Main main_;
  Dessert dessert_;
public:
  Dish(int id) : DishBase(id) {}
  const Appetizer& get_appetizer() { return appetizer_; }
  const Main& get_main() { return main_; }
  const Dessert& get_dessert() { return dessert_; }
};

struct Storage {
  typedef DishBase* value_type;
  typedef std::vector<value_type> Container;
  typedef Container::const_iterator const_iterator;
  Container container;
  Storage() {
    container.push_back(new Dish<int,double,float>(0));
    container.push_back(new Dish<double,int,double>(1));
    container.push_back(new Dish<int,int,int>(2));
  }
  ~Storage() {
    // delete objects
  }
  const_iterator begin() { return container.begin(); }
  const_iterator end() { return container.end(); }  
};

int main() {
  Storage s;
  for(Storage::const_iterator it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); ++it){
    std::cout << **it << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Dessert: " << *it->get_dessert() << std::endl; // ??
  }
  return 0;
}
```

The tricky part is here, in the `main()` function:

```
    std::cout << "Dessert: " << *it->get_dessert() << std::endl; // ??
```

How can I access the dessert? I don't even know the Dessert type (it is templated), let alone the complete type of the object that I'm getting from the storage.

This is just a toy example, but I think my code reduces to this. I'd just like to pass those `Dish` classes around, and different parts of the code will access different parts of it (in the example: its appetizer, main dish, or dessert).

Comment: Hey were you ever able to find an appropriate solution for this?

Answer (score 3):

What you have is not exactly policy-based design IMO... if it were, your class should've actually implemented (i.e. extended) the policies.

Now, back to your question/example. In your container, you store a "DishBase*". Right? From that point on, you loose any compile-time information wrt the actual type of the objects in the collection. So, I'm afraid what you try to do is provably impossible.

What you *could* do, is use an actual policy-based design, eg.

```
template<class Appetizer, class Main, class Dessert>
class Dish : public DishBase, Appetizer, Main, Dessert {
}
```

Then, you could simply use dynamic_cast to check at runtime that you can convert your object to any concrete Appetizer/Dessert/Main.

But from your description, I get the impression that you actually *need* abstract base classes (i.e. abstract base classes may be the design that makes sense for you, and not policies).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to have appropriate member functions for querying (in this case an overload for the concrete Dessert type). The policies should expose a way of discovery. Here's a short example:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

struct TA { virtual string foo() { return "TA::foo\n"; } };
struct DTA  : TA { virtual string foo() { return "DTA::foo\n"; } };

template <class T>
struct C {
    T t;
};

template <class T>
ostream& operator <<(ostream& o, C<T> c) {
    o << c.t.foo();
    return o;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) 
{
    C<DTA> c;
    cout << c;
}
```

Comment: Do I need a base class for every policy, then? If so, I could get rid of policy templates altogether and just use abstract base classes instead. But I thought I'd better use templates for efficiency ...

Comment: The example leads me to think in terms of aggregation alongwith -- as you suggest in your comment -- inheritance.

Comment: @dehmann: No, you don't need a base class. You just need that all classes has the same method signature. I think you are looking for compile time polymorphism.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that policy-based template classes are not very container friendly. I just opt for plain old polymorphism for this kind of things. I'd be interested in a solution though.

EDIT: It's perhaps not by coincidence that I cannot find any usage of stl containers throughout Alexandrescu's "Modern C++ Desing" book.

EDIT2: More details on the friction between polymorphism and genericity can be found here http://www.artima.com/cppsource/type_erasure.html. You container can perhaps be made of `boost::any` objects?